# How to create OWIN middleware per request

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, owin, unity-container, owin-middleware

I am implementing a custom owin middleware to add `CSP` header (content security policy) in response header. For `CSP` to work, the middleware needs to create a unique nonce value per request. So i have `NonceService` which creates nonce value. The custom OWIN middleware has dependency on NonceService.

However my problem is i'm not able to register custom middleware per request.

When i debug i noticed OWIN is **NOT** creating new instance of custom middleware per request and because of that same nonce value is being used for all the requests.

Below is my code

**Nonce Service**

```
public interface INonceService
{
    string GetNonce();
}

public class NonceService : INonceService
{
     private static readonly RNGCryptoServiceProvider _rng = new RNGCryptoServiceProvider();
    private readonly string _nonce;

    public NonceService(int nonceByteAmount = 32)
    {
        var nonceBytes = new byte[nonceByteAmount];
        _rng.GetBytes(nonceBytes);
        _nonce = Convert.ToBase64String(nonceBytes);
    }

    public string GetNonce()
    {
        return _nonce;
    }
}
```

**OWIN Middleware & Extension**

```
public class SecurityHeaderMiddleware : OwinMiddleware
{
    private readonly INonceService _nonceService = null;
    public SecurityHeaderMiddleware(OwinMiddleware next, INonceService nonceService) : base(next)
    {
        _nonceService = nonceService;
    }

    public override async Task Invoke(IOwinContext context)
    {
        await Next.Invoke(context);

        var nonce = _nonceService.GetNonce();
        var csp = BuildCSPHeader(nonce);
        context.Response.Headers.Add(key, csp);
    }
}

public static class OwinExtensions
{
    private const string SecurityHeaderRegistrationKey = "SecurityHeaders";

    public static IAppBuilder UseSecurityHeader(this IAppBuilder app, INonceService nonceService)
    {
        if (app == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("app");

        if (app.Properties.ContainsKey(SecurityHeaderRegistrationKey))
            return app;

        app.Use<SecurityHeaderMiddleware>(nonceService);
        app.Properties.Add(SecurityHeaderRegistrationKey, true);
        return app;
    }
}
```

I am using Unity as conatiner, so i register INonceService using `PerRequestLifetimeManager`

```
container.RegisterType<INonceService, NonceService>(new PerRequestLifetimeManager(), new InjectionConstructor(32));
```

and i register my custom middleware with OWIN in startup.cs

```
public partial class Startup
{
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    { 
        var nonceService = ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<INonceService>();
        app.UseSecurityHeader(nonceService);
    }
}
```

**Note**
If creating per request OWIN middleware is not possible then at least how should i pass per request new instance of NonceService to middleware.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the stack trace upon a null reference exception for `HttpContext` that I received, it seems that middleware is constructed in `BuildWebHost` from `Main`.

I'm using Unity too, so I changed my constructor dependency from...

`IUserRepository userRepository`

to

`Func<IUserRepository> userRepositoryFactory`

and my method call from...

```
userRepository.FetchLoggedInUser(userIdentifier);
```

to

```
userRepositoryFactory().FetchLoggedInUser(userIdentifier);
```

Conveniently, Unity automatically generates a factory, so there's no need to edit the registrations.